# after downloading a file in android where it will be stored?

Tags: android

in my application, user downloads any ebook format file from the web site and i need to handle that downloaded file in my code for the purpose of -Enable the user to view the ebook in a android device.

1. how to get control of a file after downloaded in to sdcard
2. how to change its file extension and file content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found following answers:

1. we can use file handling Technic to move ,copy etc
2. to know its MIME type  we can use setOnDownloadListner.